# creating nested array type struct datatype using spark

Tags: apache-spark, schema, azure-databricks

Can you please guide how can i create spark schema out of below delta table one of the column

col_name :
reasonDetail

datatype :

```
struct<a:string,b:array<struct<b1:string,b2:array<struct<b3:string,b4:int,b5:int>>,c:int>>>
```

I tried some of nested struct type pattern but unable to create the correct one for above column.

Comment: can you please give some detail like what you are going to do with this schema ?

Comment: Thank you for commenting, actually i am trying to consolidate schema from two different delta tables and then trying to create a new delta table out of it as a pipeline where this spark schema creation required.

Comment: I think you can get schema like `spark.table("<table_name>").schema.toDDL` this will contains all columns in your schema or `spark.table("<table_name>").select("reasonDetail").schema.toDDL` this will give you schema for specific column

Comment: Thank you but it would not work as i mentioned the column type is struct.

Comment: have you tried ? if yes, can you post code & result ?

Comment: Yes, AttributeError: Struct type object has  no attribute 'toDDL'

Comment: can you please add the code which you have tried ?

Comment: same as you told . spark.table("<table_name>").select("reasonDetail").schema.toDDL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Srinivas mentioned you can get the schema
using this query.

```
sc1 = spark.table('delta.`/samp_tbl/`').schema
print(sc1)
spark.createDataFrame(data=[],schema=sc1).printSchema()
```

[image]

Or
you can use below code for schema.

```
innermost_struct_schema = StructType([
    StructField("b3", StringType()),
    StructField("b4", IntegerType()),
    StructField("b5", IntegerType())
    ])
    
reason_detail_schema = StructType([
    StructField("reason",IntegerType()),
    StructField("reasonDetail",StructType([
        StructField("a", StringType()),
        StructField("b", ArrayType(StructType([
            StructField("b1", StringType()),
            StructField("b2", ArrayType(innermost_struct_schema)),
            StructField("c", IntegerType())
        ])))
    ]))])
    
data = [
(1,(["a_valu1",[("b1_value",[("b3_value",1,2)],34)]]))
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema=reason_detail_schema)
display(df)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It is working as expected.one more query instead of delta table as input , can we do the same by using pandas dataframe ?

Comment: Yeah. Just convert it to spark and follow above steps.
`df = spark.createDataFrame(pandasDataframe)`